# Object Oriented JavaScript - AJAX class

Tags: javascript, ajax, oop, scope, onreadystatechange

Working on an AJAX class. Here is the code:

```
function AjaxRequest(params) {
    if (params) {
        this.params = params;
        this.type = "POST";
        this.url = "login.ajax.php";
        this.contentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        this.contentLength = params.length;
    }
}

AjaxRequest.prototype.createXmlHttpObject = function() {
    try {
        this.xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            this.xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
        catch (e) {}
    }

    if (!this.xmlHttp) {
        alert("Error creating XMLHttpRequestObject");
    }
}

AjaxRequest.prototype.process = function() {
    try {
        if (this.xmlHttp) {
            this.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = this.handleRequestStateChange();
            this.xmlHttp.open(this.type, this.url, true);
            this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", this.contentType);
            this.xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", this.contentLength);
            this.xmlHttp.send(this.params);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = "";
            alert("Unable to connect to server");
        }
    }

AjaxRequest.prototype.handleRequestStateChange = function() {
    try {
        if (this.xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && this.xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            this.handleServerResponse();
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert(this.xmlHttp.statusText);
    }
}

AjaxRequest.prototype.handleServerResponse = function() {
    try {
        document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = this.xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Error reading server response");
    }
}
```

Which then is obviously instantiated like so:

```
var ajaxRequest = new AjaxRequest(params);
ajaxRequest.createXmlHttpObject();
ajaxRequest.process();
```

I'm having an issue with the `handleRequestStateChange` method, as it handles `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`. Generally, when you define a function for onreadystatechange, you don't include parentheses when it's called, for example `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleRequestStateChange;` But because I'm trying to keep `handleRequestStateChange()` in the scope of the class, I'm running into issues with onreadystatechange. The function does get called, but it seems to get stuck on a readyState of 0.

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if more details need to be included, or if I am being unclear about something.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in an anonymous function? `this.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {this.handleRequestStateChange();};`

Comment: just in case you are not aware, this has been done before http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I had tried that, and it wasn't working for me. The solution below however did work. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AjaxRequest.prototype.handleRequestStateChange = function() {
    var self = this;

    return function() {
        try {
            if (self.xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && self.xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                self.handleServerResponse();
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(self.xmlHttp.statusText);
        } 
    };
}
```

Now, when you do `this.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = this.handleRequestStateChange();`, it will return a bound function that has trapped the correct `this` reference to `self`, which is used inside the actual `onreadystatechange` function.